# SHA-2 cert for objective-c app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, sha

I was using a webservice endpoint like this http://someurl.com in my app to get some data. Now they have made this webservices SHA-2 enabled and asking us to ensure we have the SHA-2 Entrust root certs across all the servers in all environments.

How can we ensure this? 
Also the urls are now changed to https://someurl.com. Do we just need to authenticate it with didReceiveChallenge method as we do for SSL or there is some other way to handle this?

Thanks :)